# Give restricted editors access to unpublished nodes

Tags: views, users, nodes

Using Drupal 6.22.

I want to have editors create nodes (in a unpublished state) and be able to edit them. If they navigate away from the node their editing, they can't find it unless they have the full URL to it.

Is there a way to give them access without granting privileges to the admin pages and administering nodes?

I think creating a view of unpublished content and having it only show for editors is one possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let some roles manage unpublished content types without granting them the "administer nodes" permission, I installed the [view_unpublished](http://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module and then I made a view of unpublished nodes as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. This is closer to what I actually ended up doing. I decided on the publish content module. I will put this down as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the [Workbench module](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) (Drupal 7 only) will fit your needs nicely.  There's a [good screencast](http://palantir.net/blog/introducing-workbench-new-approach-managing-content-management) explaining the module on the project page.

Comment: Thanks I actually have drupal 6. This looks like a good module for when we have to upgrade.